# How can i compare JsonString Date to Short Date

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a date compare function to see if the stored Data is up to date with what i am trying to import. To do so i need to compare my stored Sales date with the Date provided in a csv file.
My stored Sales Date is in a the following format **2007-03-06T00:00:00.000Z** and the date in my csv is **05/10/2019**  I know i can try to extrct date from the jsonString but i am hoping there is a function which will allow me to do a simple compare.
Below is a simple slice i used to make it work but there should be a better way

```
date1 = "2019-05-10T00:00:00.000Z" 
date2 = "05/10/2019"

newDate = date1.slice(5,7) +"/" + date1.slice(8,10) +"/" + date1.slice(0,4)
console.log(newDate)

if (newDate != date2){
  console.log("dates dont match")
}
else {
  console.log("We have latest sale")
}
```

Comment: Convert the strings to dates with [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619202/215552) then compare with [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Convert into dates then compare on date string.

```js
date1 = "2019-05-10T00:00:00.000Z" 
date2 = "05/10/2019"
const d1 = new Date(date1)
const d2 = new Date(date2)
d1.toLocaleDateString() == d2.toLocaleDateString()
```

Comment: Note that `new Date(string)` is not guaranteed to function the same on all platforms with any format other than ISO 8601...

Comment: date1 local date string returns 5/9 if you are west of GMT (e.g. north and south america)

Comment: Once you have `Date` objects, just use `d1.valueOf() === d2.valueOf()`

Comment: @HereticMonkey please don't use === when not needed. it's heresy :D

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is comparing strings, not dates. You can use moment to convert strings to dates and compare date values

Answer (score 0):

You need dates, but probably have to strip the time FOR date1 too for those of us that aren't in GMT:

```
date1 = "2019-05-10T00:00:00.000Z" 
date2 = "05/10/2019"
const d1 = new Date(date1.slice(5,7) +"/" + date1.slice(8,10) +"/" + date1.slice(0,4))
const d2 = new Date(date2)

if (d1.valueOf() != d2.valueOf()){
  console.log("dates dont match")
}
else {
  console.log("We have latest sale")
}
```

Comment: Once you have `Date` objects, just use `d1.valueOf() === d2.valueOf()`. Not sure why people are bothering with `toLocaleDateString`...

Comment: I changed it just for you :-) @HereticMonkey